# How to use location.href instead of location.pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Javascript function looks like that:

```
       function markActiveLink() {

            var path = location.pathname;
            var home = "/";

            if (path == home)
                return
            $("a[href='" + [path || home] + "']").parents("li").each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('menu_item');
                $(this).addClass("menu_item_active");
            });
        }
```

But I want to use `document.location.href` instead of `location.pathname` to find links. I have tried just change it, but then function is not working at all -> none of my links are selected.

Code of some of my links looks like that:

```
 <ul>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserOrder.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&type=NMO">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("NMOrders.Text")%>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserOrder.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&type=MO">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("MOrders.Text")%>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserPage.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("UserPage.Text")%>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
```

And on page those links source looks like that:

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=NMO">
                    User Orders NMO
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO">
                    User Orders MO
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="/App/User/UserPage.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1">
                    User Page
                </a></li>
</ul>
```

And with those links valuse of location.pathname would be only `/App/User/UserOrder.aspx` and I need to check whole link. That's why I am trying to use location.href instead.

location.href is for example: `http://localhost/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO` 
and then location.pathname is: `/App/User/UserOrder.aspx`

Any help here much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post examples of output from location.pathname and location.href as well as examples of the links you're trying to select? That would be really helpful in figuring out the issue.

Comment: I added source code of links and also location.pathname and location.href of example link that I would like to have selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously location.href contains text (the protocol and hostname: "http://localhost/") that is not in the links.

You'll either need to remove this from location.href before doing your comparisons, or add it to your links.

Comment: It seems like it may be solution. Do you know how to remove domain name (like localhost or other in future) from location.href?

Comment: Something like `location.href.replace(/.*\/\/[^\/]*/, '')` might work. That replaces everything up to the third slash. I can't guarantee that the regex will always work as it's one I put together quickly just now.

Comment: You are right - href containing protocol and hostname were a problem. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @Cassandra: Instead of removing the protocol and hostname you can just append the query string to the path.

Answer (score 3):

Use string concatenation to include the query:

```
var path = location.pathname + location.search;
```

Comment: I checked it and it is working quite well. But it doesn't work from the start when homepage is loaded - homepage link in menu is not selected. I have to click on menu item (homepage or some other) and then it load page once again and then right menu item is selected.

Answer (score 2):

It is just `location.href` or `window.location.href` and not `document.location.href`

Try this

```
function markActiveLink() {

            var path = location.pathname;
            var home = "/", $this, href, locationHref = location.href.toLowerCase();

            if (path == home)
                return;

            $("ul li").removeClass('menu_item');

            $("ul a").each(function () {
                $this = $(this);
                href = $this.attr("href").toLowerCase();
                if(locationHref.substring(locationHref.length - href.length) == href) 
                {
                  $this.closest("li").addClass("menu_item_active");
                  return false;
                } 
            });
        }
```

Comment: I have tried using both location.href or window.location.href instead of location.pathname and none of them are working -> links are not selected.

Comment: I checked it and in simple cases it works but in my case I have problems links with ID. And still none of those links with ID are selected. I have added some more code.

Comment: I have checked it and it selects wrong link and also is looging me off when I am clicking on links.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you see in the address bar for any example and which link you want to select I can fiddle it out?

Comment: I added to my question how links look like. I would like to select for example link: <a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO">. In adress bar for page (from this link) I see http://localhost//App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO

Comment: @Cassandra - I hope you checked my edited answer, if you think it helped you please accept my answer thanks.

Comment: Of course I have checked your answer. But it didn't work in my case - none of menu items were selected.